# PHP Variable is not displaying the way it should

Tags: php

Outputting to page with echo displays a different number than what is being displayed in error log, they are 1 line apart and are not modified in between. The echo is displaying an old variable, the error log is displaying the updated variable

Added more error_log's between each step that the variable is modified, the echo uses the variable's old token number instead of the new generated token number, and error_log uses the new generated token that is done when the page loads. This is being seen on 2 computers (Both Google Chrome). The top part of the code is part of the global scope, when i comment it out $form_token no longer outputs anything

```php
error_log("TOKENA: " . $form_token); // undefined 
$form_token = generate_token(); // token generated (value is 190791)
error_log("TOKENB: " . $form_token); // Outputs 190791

....

<?php error_log("VARIABLE SHOULD BE SAME: " . $form_token); ?> // Outputs 190791
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="' . $form_token . '">'; ?> // Outputs 827194
<?php echo "VARIABLE SHOULD BE SAME: " . $form_token; ?> // Outputs 827194
```

No error messages besides the undefined variable, which was expected, everything looks like it is going through but variables are not matching up. Only 1 assignment of $form_token takes place yet it is giving 2 different values. The values that are being outputted to HTML appear to be values that were supposed to be used for the new variables in the previous page load

Looking for any assistance as to why variable is being displayed different just 1 line apart, with the only difference being one is outputted to page via HTML and echo, the other sent to log

Comment: I'm not that great at PHP, but I am thinking it's because it isn't a global variable?

Comment: it should be a global variable, when I comment it out, the variable is undefined throughout the entire page

Comment: What is this `generate_token()` you speak of? It's not part of the PHP core, so it must be a custom function. I would be looking inside that as a first step

Comment: generate_token returns a random 9 digit number, which is then assigned to $form_token, an output of the number inside generate_token() is the same as the error_logs, but the echo'ed output is still different, one way I tested without was to set $form_token to NULL instead of being pulled from a function, and the echo'ed output is still different.

Comment: what is the scope of this portion of code ? global or inside a function ?

Comment: did error_log and echo $form_token in the same page / php file and both called after $form_token = generate_token(); initiation ? do you use any looping where $form_token = generate_token(); is repeated ? 

can you post the full code with the generator function ?

Comment: may be a cache issue. press CTRL+F5 to be sure is a new page, or try to open dev tools with chrome (Ctrl+shift+I) , go to settings (3 dots menu , upper right, or press F1) , section Network, check disable cache (while DevTools is open),

Comment: Scope: Global, error_log and echo are on the same page as where $form_token is set, with $form_token = generate_token() being up in the <?php head and the error_log and echo being inside an HTML form

Comment: Disabled network cache, token being generated and error_log'ed is still different than what is being echo'ed, also still only 1 assignment of $form_token taking place

Comment: can you add .new DateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). to each log output and show us the log.

Comment: i have an idea, in generate_token function add echo <br>'called<br>'; to detect how many generate_token is called , or set a variable like $count = 0 before the function and $count++ inside the function, after that echo that $count variable, because it seems generate_token function is called multiple times

Comment: Identified the issue, my session handler got spaghettied and was forcing a redirect to itself. Original code should work after I get spaghetti cleaned up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue lied not with the code itself but with the session handler I was using. Session handler was causing multiple redirects to the page which was generating a new code on each load, so it was caught between different loads. After patching the session handler, original code posted above is working as intended with only 1 output being generated